# Problem in opening Sub Activity of ActivityGroup

Tags: android

I am working with ActivityGroup and I want to open an sub activity of the ActivityGroup on selection of another tab. Please anyone let me know if it is possible or not?

example - I have tab1 and I open a subActivity(say activity "A") in the same tab using ActivityGroup and now when I click on tab2 I should open the same Activity "A" with all its contents.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you please post some code? The XML file for the layout?
You have a tabwidget inside of a actvitygroup? I can't help you without more details

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I really, strongly urge you to stop using ActivityGroup.  This has been deprecated.

The fragment support library provides a much better way to do these things.  The 3.2 version includes an example showing how to use it with the tab widget. See the ["Fragment Tabs"](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/index.html) example and the [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) documentation.

These can be used down to Android 1.6.

(There are also lots of demos there for other things you can do with fragments.)

Comment: can you give some example for the same and can we use this stuff in 2.2?

Comment: The first link is to an example.  As I said, this can be used down to Android 1.6.

Comment: I dont think that Fragment will do the work of ActivityGroup. Will it?

Comment: It is explained in the [TabActivity docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) how to use Fragments to achieve tabs. This is the best approach.

Comment: You can't be serious? This is the worst looking API I have ever seen, what was wrong with ActivityGroup? It worked great!! Now I have to switch to this crap?

Comment: Fragments are tons better than ActivityGroup.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I thing it can be done :

open the sub-activity just as normally you do, create certain static variable to hold data between two opened activities, be it static bundle or strings, when ever you perform some action on activity ex: type some thing in edit text, save the content in those static variables, in the onResume of the activity, put those data from variables in views........

See if it works........

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

if not found helpful then please provide me some more details about flow and if possible then put your (xml/java) code. so i can clearly understand the problem.

Let me know it's useful for you or not  by comment ?