# Android - Change content view of TabHost

Tags: android

I try to create a android application with tabHost and I would like to avoid to set intent(activity) for the content of these tabs.

I succeed to create my tabMenu but I would like to change the view of one tab.
How I can do that ?

For example I have one view for Tab1 and two views for Tab2 (when the user click on the button of Tab2_view1 then the content change to Tab2_view2 and the indicator doesn't change (stay on "tab2")).

I hope it is possible but I don't find the way to do that without using different activities for each tabs.
Maybe my conception is bad (I am novice in Android dev.)...

Thank you very much for your help,

Fred

Comment: please be careful with tags ... a tag should make sense on it's own for more information search [meta] for `tags`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has `ActivityGroup` for the same purpose that you are looking for. By using `ActivityGroup` you can show multiple views in a single Tab by maintaining the stack of the Views.

[ActivityGroup Example 1](http://androidgenuine.com/)

[ActivityGroup Example 2](http://richipal.com/post/2624844577)

Fragment - Answer to me by [hackbod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634233/problem-in-opening-sub-activity-of-activitygroup)

Comment: yes it is but still it is being used, else you can use Fragment.

Comment: Thanks for your answers :)
Do you have a example of Fragment utilisation ?